# How to set Bootstrap Glyphicons as shortcut icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to set Bootstrap Glyphicons as shortcut icon?

For website we use

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logo-small.jpg">
```

How to set Bootstrap Glyphicons as shortcut icon for `glyphicon glyphicon-cloud`

Comment: Try <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/logo-small.jpg" />

Comment: `href="images/logo-small.jpg">` is working properly insted of available image at images folder i want to set `glyphicon glyphicon-cloud` as my `shortcut icon`

Answer (score 10):

You can't directly. The twitter bootstrap icons are a webfont, and a shortcut icon needs to be an image.

Use an image editor to create the favicon image file manually.

**UPDATE:** The bootstrap icons are from [Glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/), and their free download package includes the bootstrap cloud icon as a PNG. You will need to make this into a 16x16 px (normal res) or 32x32 px (for retina) png, which will then be good to reference as you already know how:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/cloud.png">
```

Comment: @xrcwrn i don't know if this helped you or not, but it was a great answer and worked well for me... if it helped you, don't forget to mark it as the answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap doc on their site, they have given various classes of  Glyphicons icons.
Here you just have to include their Glyphicons image in resource folder of your project.
Various classes given by them are 
**icon-glass , icon-music , icon-search , icon-envelope and many more...**

Here you just have to add in your HTML page

```
//it is for search icon
<i class="icon-search "></i>

//it is for user icon
<i class="icon-user "></i>
```

Comment: check on bootstrap site what is the icon name for glyphicon-cloud or you may check in CSS file